# Getting zero record in user meta data in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, user-roles, user-data, meta-query, usermetadata

I am trying to get user list with specifice role and who is register between two date. I tried But getting zero record (**it has record in database **)in result.

```
 $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
 
    if(isset($_GET['interviewr'])) {
        $interviewr = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['interviewr'] );
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'interviewr',
            'value' => $interviewr,
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }
      if(isset($_GET['applicantstatus'])) {
        $applicantstatus = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['applicantstatus'] );
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'ur_user_status',
            'value' => $applicantstatus,
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }
      if(isset($_GET['startdate'])) {
        $startdate = date(ymd,strtotime( $_GET['startdate'] ));
        $enddate   = date(ymd,strtotime( $_GET['enddate'] ));
        $meta_query[] = 
          array(
                    'key' => 'user_registered',
                    'value' =>array( $startdate,$enddate),
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                    'type' => 'DATE'
                );
      }
         
 $args = array(
        'role' => 'applicant',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => $meta_query
    );
 
  
        $search_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
   $userlist=$search_query->get_results();
```

Comment: Are you sure `ymd` instead of `Ymd`?

Comment: wrap ```ymd``` in quotes

Comment: I already tried it but not working.